# R Splitting strings by multiple splitting criteria and storing the splitting criteria

Tags: r, stringr

I'm trying to split a string by multiple criteria and store the splitting criteria for each split.

I have been trying to use the `stringr::str_split` package but cannot pass more than one splitting criteria to the function.

For example if I have the following string:

```r
data = "Julie (title) : This is the text Julie has: said. Extra sentence one. Extra sentence 2 and so on. Rt Hon Ellen: This is the text Ellen has said in response to Julie. TITLE OF SECTION Julie: More words from Julie."
```

and splitting criteria:

```r
names = c("Julie:", "Ellen:")
```

I would like an output like this:

```
data.frame(Names = c("Julie:", "Ellen:","Julie:"),
           text = c(" This is the text Julie has: said. Extra sentence one. Extra sentence 2 and so on. ", "This is the text Ellen has said in response to Julie.","More words from Julie."))
```

Comment: Would the value in `data` always be in the same order as `names` ? So is it always that "Julie" would come first and then "Ellen" in `data` ?

Comment: No, the names could feature in any order or not at all in the string. The idea being each original data string (I have many) is a day of speech from Members of Parliament (MPs) and I have a list of MPs. I would like to know what MPs said what text by storing it in a data frame as above.

Comment: @Julie Mugford please see my solution below and upvote/accept it as an answer if it performs as expected. If not tell me your error and I can adjust my solution.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen your comments in coatless's answer and created a sample data, which probably reflects what you said. One way would be the following. I first create a data frame. I split the string for each sentence using `unnest_tokens()`. Then, I split the sentences using `separate()`. Finally, I replaced NAs with person's name. I hope this will help you to some extent.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(tidytext)
library(zoo)

so <- tibble(text = "Ana: I went to school today. I learned text mining. Bob: That is great! Ana: I know what to do: practice.")

unnest_tokens(so, output = sentence,
              input = text,
              token = "sentences") %>% 
separate(col = sentence, into = c("person", "sentence"), sep = ": ",
         extra = "merge", fill = "left") %>% 
mutate(person = na.locf(person))

# A tibble: 4 x 2
#  person sentence                    
#  <chr>  <chr>                       
#1 ana    i went to school today.     
#2 ana    i learned text mining.      
#3 bob    that is great!              
#4 ana    i know what to do: practice.
```

Answer (score 0):

Long-winded inefficient Base R solution:

```
# Store a vector of the names: 

text_names <- c("Julie", "Ellen")

# Create a dataframe of the patterns: 

pattern_search <- data.frame(name_search = c(paste0(text_names, ":"),

                                             paste0(text_names, " :"),

                                             paste0(text_names, ".* :")),

                             stringsAsFactors = F)

# Split the text into sentences: 

split_text <- data.frame(sentences = trimws(unlist(strsplit(df$Text, "[.]")), "both"), stringsAsFactors = F)

# Extract the names, store them in a vector:

names_in_order <- gsub("[[:punct:]]|\\s+.*",

                       "",

                       regmatches(grep(paste0(pattern_search$name_search, collapse = "|"),

                           split_text$sentences, value = T),

                      regexpr(paste0(pattern_search$name_search, collapse =  "|"),

                              grep(paste0(pattern_search$name_search, collapse = "|"),

                                   split_text$sentences, value = T))))

# Store a logical vector denoting which elements the names should go: 

split_text$who_said_this <- grepl(paste0(pattern_search$name_search, collapse = "|"),

                                  split_text$sentences)

# Replace all occurences of TRUE with the elements of the vector of names: 

split_text$who_said_this[which(split_text$who_said_this == TRUE)] <- names_in_order

# Replace FALSE with NA values: 

split_text$who_said_this[which(split_text$who_said_this == "FALSE")] <- NA

# Store a vector that's values denote the number of times dialogue changes between the names:

split_text$speech_group_no <- ave(split_text$who_said_this,

                                  split_text$who_said_this,

                                  FUN = seq.int)

# Apply a function to fill NA values with the non-NA value above it: 

split_text <- data.frame(lapply(split_text, function(x){na.omit(x)[cumsum(!is.na(x))]}),

                         stringsAsFactors = F)

# Row-wise concatenate the dataframe by group: 

split_text <- aggregate(list(sentences = c(split_text$sentences)), 

                 list(speech_group_no = paste0(split_text$who_said_this, " - ", split_text$speech_group_no)),

                 paste0,

                 sep = ". ")

# Flatten list vector into a character vector and clean up punctuation: 

split_text$sentences <- gsub(" [,] ", " ", sapply(split_text$sentences, toString))

# Order the dialogue:

split_text <- split_text[match(split_text$speech_group_no,

                 paste(names_in_order, ave(names_in_order, names_in_order, FUN = seq.int), sep = " - ")),]
```

Data:

```
df <-  structure(
list(Text = "Julie (title) : This is the text Julie has: said. Extra sentence one. Extra sentence 2 and so on. Rt Hon Ellen: This is the text Ellen has said in response to Julie. TITLE OF SECTION Julie: More words from Julie."),
class = "data.frame",
row.names = c(NA,-1L)
  )
```

Comment: @ Julie Mugford. The above solves your problem. If you find it doesn’t please tell me your error and I’ll correct it. Otherwise like and accept it is as an answer.